# Iterating on a file and comparing values using python

Tags: python, comparison, iteration

I have a section of code that opens files containing information with wavenumber and intensity like this:

```
500.21506 -0.00134
500.45613 0.00231
500.69720 -0.00187
500.93826 0.00129
501.17933 -0.00049
501.42040 0.00028
501.66147 0.00114
501.90253 -0.00036
502.14360 0.00247
```

My code attempts to parse the information between two given wavelengths: lowwav and highwav. I would like to print only the intensities of the wavenumbers that fall between lowwav and highwav. My entire code looks like:

```
import datetime
import glob
path = '/Users/140803/*' 
files = glob.glob(path)

for line in open('sfit4.ctl', 'r'): 
            x = line.strip()
            if x.startswith('band.1.nu_start'):
                a,b = x.split('=')
                b = float(b)
                b = "{0:.3f}".format(b)
                lowwav = b
            if x.startswith('band.1.nu_stop'):
                a,b = x.split('=')
                b = float(b)
                b = "{0:.3f}".format(b)
                highwav = b 

with open('\\_spec_final.t15', 'w') as f:
    with open('info.txt', 'rt') as infofile:
        for count, line in enumerate(infofile): 
            lat = float(line[88:94]) 
            lon = float(line[119:127])
            year = int(line[190:194])
            month = int(line[195:197])
            day = int(line[198:200])
            hour = int(line[201:203])
            minute = int(line[204:206])
            second = int(line[207:209])
            dur = float(line[302:315])
            numpoints = float(line[655:660])
            fov = line[481:497] # field of view?
            sza = float(line[418:426])
            snr = 0.0000 
            roe = 6396.2 
            res = 0.5000
            lowwav = float(lowwav)
            highwav = float(highwav)
            spacebw = (highwav - lowwav)/ numpoints

            d = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
            f.write('{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>8.1f}'.format(sza,roe,lat,lon,snr)) # line 1
            f.write("\n")
            f.write('{:>10d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}'.format(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)) # line 2
            f.write("\n")
            f.write( ('{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)) + "UT Solar Azimuth:" + ('{:>6.3f}'.format(sza)) + " Resolution:" + ('{:>6.4f}'.format(res)) + " Duration:" + ('{:>6.2f}'.format(dur))) # line 3
            f.write("\n")
            f.write('{:>21.13f}{:>26.13f}{:>24.17e}{:>12f}'.format(lowwav,highwav,spacebw,numpoints)) # line 4
            f.write("\n")


            with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
                for line in g:
                    wave_no, tensity = [float(item) for item in line.split()]
                    if lowwav <= wave_no <= highwav :
                        f.write(str(tensity) + '\n')


g.close()        
f.close()
infofile.close()
```

Right now, everything works fine except the last part where I compare wavelengths and print out the intensities corresponding to wavelengths between lowwav and highwav. No intensities are printing into the output file.

Comment: are you missing a '5' on the first line of data?

Comment: yes - copy/paste mistake

Comment: Okay, the final `close()` calls are useless since you are using `with` everywhere. AFAIK the code should work. Are you sure that there are any values inside that range? Try to print the values of `wave_no` that you parse and see if something is between `lowwav` and `highwav`.

Comment: there are values within there. where should I put the close() calls?

Comment: if I write print(wave_no) before the if-loop, it prints them all fine. I feel something is wrong with the comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you iterate over the file `g` you are effectively moving its "file pointer". So the second loop finds the file at the beginning and doesn't produce any value.

Secondly, you are producing all these `nums` lists, but every iteration of the lop shadows the previous value, making it unreachable.

Either you want to collected all the values and then iterate on those:

```
with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
    all_nums = []
    for line in g:
        all_nums.append([float(item) for item in line.split()])

    for nums in all_nums:
        if (lowwav - nums[0]) < 0 or (highwav - nums[0]) > 0 :
            f.write(str(nums[1]))
            f.write('\n')
        else: break
```

Or just do everything inside the first loop (this should be more efficient):

```
with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
    for line in g:
        nums = [float(item) for item in line.split()]
        if (lowwav - nums[0]) < 0 or (highwav - nums[0]) > 0 :
            f.write(str(nums[1]))
            f.write('\n')
        else: break
```

Also note that the `break` statement will stop the processing of the values when the condition is false for the first time, you probably want to remove it.

---

This said, note that your code prints all values where `nums[0]` that **either** are bigger than `lowwav`, or smaller than `highwav`, which means that if `lowwav < highwav` **every** number value will be printed. You probably want to use `and` in place of `or` if you want to check whether they are between `lowwav` and `highwav`.  Moreover in python you could just write `lowwav < nums[0] < highwav` for this.

I would personally use the following:

```
with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
    for line in g:
        wave_no, intensity = [float(item) for item in line.split()]
        if lowwav < wave_no < highwav:
            f.write(str(intensity)+'\n')
```

Comment: the 'or' has to be an 'and' if i understand OP correctly. The frequency has to be bounded between these two values. Also why 'break' and not 'continue'?

Comment: thanks! it is now writing data to the output file, however it is not implementing the comparison correctly: it is printing out every single intensity value regardless of the wavenumber - do you know why that may be?

Comment: when I change the "or" to an "and" - there is no output at all

Comment: @alli What thresholds are you using? Change the 'break' to 'continue' as well

Comment: lowwav = 7765 highwav = 8005

Comment: @alli I've edited my answer. Initially it outputted every number due to the `or`, when using `and` it didn't print output probably because the first line didn't satisfy the condition and the `break` stopped the loop.

Comment: @alli Just grab the last piece Bakuriu wrote. That should work.

Comment: the files contain wavelengths from 550 - 2249

Comment: @alli You want to include the `lowwav` and `highwav` values? I.e. if you have a wave number equal to `7765` should this be considered between `7765` and `8005`? If so change `<` to `<=` in the last snippet. AFAIK in your original code you used a strict `<` so it would be excluded.

Comment: @Bakuriu I wrote in the suggested code but nothing is outputting in the file (yes I will change the < to <= thanks for the tip)

Comment: @alli Are you using the `with statement to open `f` too? Otherwise you may have to `f.close()` it for the output to be performed. If still doesn't work I suggest that you update your answer with the code you are *currently* using so that we can check if there are other issues at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Split each line by white space, unpack the split list to two names `wavelength` and `intensity`.

`[line.split() for line in r]` makes

```
500.21506 -0.00134
500.45613 0.00231
```

to

```
[['500.21506', '-0.00134'], ['500.45613', '0.00231']]
```

This listcomp `[(wavelength, intensity) for wavelength,intensity in lol if low <= float(wavelength) <= high]` returns

```
[('500.21506', '-0.00134'), ('500.45613', '0.00231')]
```

If you join them back `[' '.join((w, i)) for w,i in [('500.21506', '-0.00134'), ('500.45613', '0.00231')]` you get `['500.21506 -0.00134', '500.45613 0.00231']`

Use listcomp to filter out wavelength. And join `wavelength` and `intensity` back to string and write to file.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as r, open('\\_spec_final.t15', 'w') as w:
    lol = (line.split() for line in r)
    intensities = (' '.join((wavelength, intensity)) for wavelength,intensity in lol if low <= float(wavelength) <= high)
    w.writelines(intensities)
```

If you want to output to terminal do `print(list(intensities))` instead of `w.writelines(intensities)`
Contents of `data.txt`;

```
500.21506 -0.00134
500.45613 0.00231
500.69720 -0.00187
500.93826 0.00129
501.17933 -0.00049
501.42040 0.00028
501.66147 0.00114
501.90253 -0.00036
502.14360 0.00247
```

Output when `low` is 500 and `high` is 50`;

```
['500.21506 -0.00134', '500.45613 0.00231']
```

Comment: the sfit4.ctl file is simply where I read in the highwav and lowwav number, I don't want to do anything else with that file

Comment: sorry I am so new to python I am just confused. I don't understand why you line.split in the sfit4.ctl file at all. and I don't understand the .join function

Comment: thank you for the explanation - I understand! however, still no output :(

Comment: do `print(intensities)` instead of `w.writelines(intensities)` and post it.

Comment: this is what I get: 
econ2-205-94-dhcp:CALPY output alli$ python readinfo1.py
[]
[]
[]
[] - so it looks like empty arrays or lists?

Comment: My code assumes `info.txt` contains lines like this `500.21506 -0.00134`. If this is not the case, my code won't work

Comment: no. info.txt contains very different information that also needs to be incorporated into the output file... which is why I have the loops set up as they were bc each line in the info.txt file pertains to a different .txt file with the wavenumber, intensity info

Comment: Your question is how to filter some wavelength and output the desired intensities. That's what I'v done. F.e. `data.txt` contains the lines starting with `500.21506 -0.00134`.

Comment: yes - I think your code is logical enough. for some reason it is still not producing the correct output for me but thank you for your help and explanation

Comment: check [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)